# how can i use the optimize.minimize function with additional arguments?

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, scipy

This is just a test function i made. Given a list, if i can add one value to the list, what value would minimize the list's variance?

```
from scipy import optimize

def var_func(x,observations):
    path_var=variance([x]+observations)
    return path_var


observations=[15,24,46,23,54]
var_func_bet=optimize.minimize(var_func,100,args=(observations))
```

I've succesfully used optimize.minimize on single variate functions with success, but here it doesn't work.

Trying the above code gave me the error:

```
TypeError: can't convert type 'ndarray' to numerator/denominator
```

Comment: `(observations)` is just `observations`; the () are ignored.  `(observations,)` is a tuple with one element.  The comma is important.

Comment: I made the edit but im getting the same error.

Comment: what is np.array(100)+observations?

Comment: array([115, 124, 146, 123, 154])

Comment: What's this `variance`?

Comment: I think it has to do with the variance function, replacing it with sum makes the function work

Comment: it's from the statistics package. from statistics import variance

Answer (score 0):

Use [numpy.var](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.var.html) for computing the variance and make sure you pass your arguments as a tuple (see hpaulj's comment):

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

def var_func(x,observations):
    return np.var([x]+observations)


observations = [15,24,46,23,54]
var_func_bet = minimize(var_func, 100, args=(observations,))
```